# Typescript 0.9.5 compiler error with IgniteUI I don't understand

Tags: typescript

I am using the Infragistics IgniteUi library.
I have the following code

```
var col1 = $("#grid1").igGrid("option", "columns")[1];
```

col1 is a plain object like this

```
{ key:"aa", headerText:"bb"}
```

I have attached one of my own properties to this column eg

```
{ key:"aa", headerText:"bb", mine:"cc"}
```

So when I do this,

```
var col1 = $("#grid1").igGrid("option", "columns")[1];
var value1 = col1.mine;
```

the compiler doesn't like it and gives me the error

Error   1   The property 'mine' does not exist on value of type 'HTMLElement'

I can get around the compile error by defining col1 as any ie

```
var col1:any = $("#grid1").igGrid("option", "columns")[1];
```

But I wasn't expecting the compiler to think col1 is an 'HTMLElement'

my ignite.d.ts file has a definition for columns as

```
interface IgGrid {
    ..
    columns?: IgGridColumn[];
}

interface IgGridColumn {
    headerText?: string;
    key?: string;
    formatter?: any;
    format?: string;
    dataType?: string;
    width?: string;
    hidden?: boolean;
    template?: string;
    unbound?: boolean;
    group?: any[];
    rowspan?: number;
    formula?: string;
    unboundValues?: any[];
}
```

So I would have thought the compiler to give the error 'mine' is not a property of IgGridColumn.

Is my understanding wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the IgGridColumn interface to include your custom properties, like this:

```
interface IgGridColumn {
    mine: string;
}
```

Not only will this solve the compiler error, it will supply type checking on the value.

If you find that you aren't getting an IgGridColumn back from your jQuery call, you can use the same trick:

```
interface JQuery {
    igGrid(a: string, b: string) : IgGridColumn[];
}
```

That allows you to continue to use the inferred type here:

```
var col1 = $("#grid1").igGrid("option", "columns")[1];
```

Comment: Thanks. I just realized what I should have done. I should have said var col1:IgGridColumn = $("#grid1").igGrid("option", "columns")[1]; Then the compiler works correctly.

Comment: You can actually do better - you can tell the compiler that the igGrid function returns an IgGridColumn. I'll add that to my answer.